# gradle build hangs when using azure application insights appender in logback.xml

Tags: azure, spring-boot, gradle, azure-application-insights, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am using azure application insights for logging in my application, It is a spring boot application with gradle. I am using application insights as an appender in my logback.xml
The application works fine and logging works fine. But when I try to build my  application using "gradle build" the build gets stuck and runs forever.

[image]

The application builds fine if the application insights appender is removed from logback.xml file. I tried adding ApplicationInsights.xml and still the issue exists

My build.gradle is as below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release" }
        maven { url "http://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${spring_boot_version}"
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:propdeps-plugin:${propdeps_plugin_version}"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.org.detoeuf:swagger-codegen-plugin:${swagger_codegen_version}"
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:${net_ltgt_version}"
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:${sonar_version}"
    }
}

// Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt'
apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

group = 'com.test.project'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8 

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
       dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
    api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty"
    api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"
    api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
    api "org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2"

    api "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config"
    api "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-security:${spring_cloud_security_version}"
    api "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${swagger_version}"
    api "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:${swagger_version}"
    api ("net.sf.dozer:dozer:${dozer_version}") {
        exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "slf4j-log4j12"
    }
    api "com.zaxxer:HikariCP:${hikari_version}"
    api "org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgres_version}"
    api "org.hibernate:hibernate-java8"
    api "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0"
    api "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz"
    api "org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.3"
    api "org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-jobs:2.2.3"
    api "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.2.4.RELEASE"

    api "com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter:1.0.0-BETA"
    api "com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-logback:2.0.+"

    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation "junit:junit:${junit_version}"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
    testImplementation "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:${javax_servlet_version}"
    testImplementation "io.rest-assured:rest-assured:${rest_assured_version}"
    testImplementation "io.rest-assured:spring-mock-mvc:${rest_assured_version}"
    testImplementation "com.h2database:h2"
    testImplementation "org.hsqldb:hsqldb"
    testImplementation "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.6.0"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:2.0.0-beta.5"
    testImplementation "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:2.0.0-beta.5"

}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-boot-bom:${spring_azure_version}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${spring_cloud_version}"
    }
}
```

My logback.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="logs/project_name" />
    <property name="LOG_PATTERN"
        value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />

    <appender name="CONSOLE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ROLLINGFILE"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder
            class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">

            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="aiAppender" 
        class="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.logback.ApplicationInsightsAppender"> 
    </appender> 

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="ROLLINGFILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="aiAppender" /> 
    </root>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate.engine" level="ERROR" />

</configuration>
```

My application.yml properties are

```
project:
    artifactId: project-artifact
    name: Project name
    version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    description: Project desc

server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
     contextPath: /api

azure:
   application-insights:
      instrumentation-key: instrumentation-key
      enabled: true
      web:
         enabled: true
```

I tried adding ApplicationInsights.xml as below but still the build hangs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings" schemaVersion="2014-05-30">


  <!-- The key from the portal: -->

  <InstrumentationKey>instrumentation key</InstrumentationKey>


  <!-- HTTP request component (not required for bare API) -->

  <TelemetryModules>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebRequestTrackingTelemetryModule"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebSessionTrackingTelemetryModule"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.modules.WebUserTrackingTelemetryModule"/>
  </TelemetryModules>

  <!-- Events correlation (not required for bare API) -->
  <!-- These initializers add context data to each event -->

  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add   type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationIdTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebOperationNameTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebSessionTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserTelemetryInitializer"/>
    <Add type="com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.extensibility.initializers.WebUserAgentTelemetryInitializer"/>

  </TelemetryInitializers>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

Please suggest if I am missing anything

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by changing logback.xml to logback-spring.xml